How to find coords of an element in pywinauto python
How to find co ords of an element easily using python
I am doing a desktop application automation in which I have to click on a element which requires me to use scrollbar
So, in order to make use of scroll functionality I need to find out co ords. How can I do that?

There is a wrapper method .wheel_mouse_input(...) which doesn't need coordinates, only number of steps up or down (negative integer parameter value). Also if you explain your task in more details: what you want to achieve by such scrolling, maybe even better solution could be suggested.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I am trying to find an element on a pane, which will be visible only if I scroll the pane. I am using UIA backend. Please suggest how do I do it, and also I can't find the scrollbar title as well from print_control_identifiers

Pane is always a pain! :) Only methods with suffix _input would work for it. But every action will be a little bit blind. :( Custom controls can't be automated nice way using Microsoft UI Automation API in the vast majority of cases. If it is Qt or WPF, there is a potential way using DLL injection approach. But we have prototype for WPF only.

I'm still stuck with this one. Can you please help me in solving this. It would be of great help if I can just get ahead with one step and I will be done
